# Solving an equation involving square roots

Tags: problem-solving, real-numbers, radicals

I'm having trouble with a problem that involves square roots, and I'm hoping that someone here can help me figure it out.

The problem states that for which real numbers $x$ does the equation $\sqrt{x^2-1}=\sqrt{x+1}\cdot\sqrt{x-1}$ hold true? The answer choices are:

(a) all real numbers

(b) all real numbers such that $|x|\geq1$

(c) all real numbers such that $x\geq1$

(d) none of the above

Here's what I've tried so far: I squared both sides of the equation to get $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)=x^2-1$. This means that the equation holds true for all real numbers $x$.

However, I'm not sure if my solution is correct. Can someone please confirm if my answer is correct or if I made a mistake somewhere? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By definition (high school algebra) , $\sqrt a\sqrt b=\sqrt {ab}$ holds, iff $a,b≥0$. Therefore, you have : $$\begin{cases}x-1≥0\\x+1≥0\end{cases}\implies x≥1\thinspace .$$

Comment: If you're allowed imaginary solutions to the square roots, doesn't it still hold if $x=0$?  It seems like the problems occur when $x<-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that complex numbers are forbidden, and we treat the square root of a negative as “bad!”. The question is still interesting if $\Bbb C$ is involved though.

It seems to me the question-asker is really just trying to get you to think about when things are defined. Hint: you’ve shown that, so long as everything is defined, the equation should hold. So what conditions do we need on $x$ to ensure those square roots exist?

Comment: In my high-school algebra book there is a statement:  "The square root symbol $\color{red}{\large{\sqrt {\cdot }}}$ is defined if and only if, for non-negative real numbers" .

Comment: @lonestudent But that is a high-school algebra book. The square root symbol is still sometimes used when dealing with complex numbers and is frequently used in abstract algebra for more general purposes